# How to reset line spacing when needed and set it again

Tags: line-spacing, class-options

I am using a journal's class file and it has more than 1 line spacing for paragraphs. However, I would like to disable it when I put some pseudocode with `algorithm` package and then enable it again.

If I give you an example over MS Word's settings: I want to set "before/after" spacing to 0 and "line spacing" to "single" and then when I complete my algorithm, I want to release the control to the class file again.

Is there any way to make that happen?

Here is the link to the addressed class file: [Informs3 Class file](https://lotokolik.com/informs3.cls)

Comment: try with the commands `\SingleSpacedXII` and `\OneAndAHalfSpacedXII` (untested as you didn't provide a compilable example).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks man, it worked!

Comment: I'm not a man, I'm a woman.

Comment: sorry my bad, I am not familiar with your culture etc. thanks though :)